# How many telephone numbers that are seven digits in length have exactly five 6's?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

How many phone numbers that are seven digits in length, have exactly five 6's?

My attempt: {{6,6,6,6,6}{ , }}

$(5(top) 5(bottom)) * (18(top) 2(bottom)) = 153$

my reasoning is that the first subset containing the 6's must all be 6, so when I do the permutation I get 1, now on the second subset, there are 18 numbers remaining (9+9) since 6 is not allowed and I can only pick two, so when I do the permutation i get 153.
so 1*153=153.
However, I feel like this is wrong, if so can someone point me down the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The **locations** of the $6$'s can be chosen in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways. For each such choice, the remaining two slots can be filled in $9^2$ ways.

Comment: so  my answer comes to 21*(9^2), which yields me 1701. is that correct

Comment: Yes, that's right. That is under the assumption that all strings of digits are allowed.

Comment: Im confused as to why I do 7!/(5!(7-5)! instead  7!/(7-5)!

Comment: Because the $6$'s are indistinguishable. We are choosing places for them, and leaving reserved signs on the other places. So we are making a word of length $7$ with $5$ copies of $6$ and $2$ copies of R (reserved).

Comment: okay, so say, I wanted to find the amount of numbers that have exactly five digits greater than 6. I would do ((7 5) +(7 5) +(7 5) ) * (9^2)

Comment: because there are only 3 other digits greater than 6

Comment: The locations of the "big" digits can be chosen in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways. These can be filled by digits greater than $6$ (that is, $7$, $8$, or $9$) in $3^5$ ways. The remaining two spots can be filled with small digits, $0$ to $6$, in $7^2$ ways, for a total of $\binom{7}{5}3^57^2$ ways.

Comment: Okay, now lets hope I get this one correct, say I wanted to find numbers that have exactly three 7's and exactly two 5's, so going off from I think I know, (7 3)*(7 2) * 8^2 . Is this correct and suppose I wanted to find instead of and , the or of this question, like exactly three 7's or exactly two 5's

Comment: The locations of the $7$'s can be chosen in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways. For each of these, the locations of the $5$'s can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways (here you have a slip). And then the rest can be filled in $8^2$ ways.

Comment: why is the second part (4 2) ?

Comment: Because $3$ of the $7$ slots are already occupied by $7$'s, leaving $4$. We choose $2$ of these $4$ for the $5$'s.